# Friends of friends commenting on pictures

Tags: facebook

I tagged a friend in a picture but it’s now being commented on by people I don’t know.  Is there a way to ensure only the intended audience can see it?

Answer (score 0):

When you share a picture, you can share it only with specific people. That would essentially lock it from any other user from seeing or commenting. As far as restricting comments, I don't think you can do that specifically without restricting the audience first.